# Extending non local class with coffee script

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, coffeescript

I'm trying to write an overlay in google maps v3 using coffeescript to extend their overlayview.

```
class MyOverlay extends google.maps.OverlayView
  constructor: (@bounds, @map) ->
    console.log("i'm being built")
```

Currently if I declare this in a standard coffeescript file it will fail with 'Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined '. In order to get it to work I have to put the class declarations within the onready block like:

```
$ ->
  class MyOverlay extends google.maps.OverlayView
```

That works, but I was wondering if there's a cleaner way.

Comment: Does `google.maps.OverlayView` exist right after the Google Maps JavaScript file is loaded or is there some script loading chicanery going on? If it is then you'd just have to order things properly, otherwise you're probably stuck with your `$ ->` trick.

Comment: Ugh I'm so dumb, it was just the order. For some reason I was thinking local js would execute before the remote script. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The order of the scripts was wrong. Just load the remote script before your own coffeescript.